# Left join grouped data(with min/max) without losing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, left-join, min

Hello and thank you in advance! I have the following query that retrieves the table i need (highlighted in green). The top select statement gets the min(eventdate) and the bottom select statement (that is Unioned) gets a concatenation of min(eventdate) and max(eventdate). This is most important to maintain.  This returns the data just fine, but now i'm stuck having to join the rest of the data to this table (highlighted in red).

How can I join  without having to group all my columns and lose some data. If you look at the image you can see the data returned  because event time doesn't need to be grouped, it's all the same. However, this is not always the case, event time changes even for the same ID. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
(Select  id,__DisplayName, LEFT(cast(min(EventDate) as varchar), len(min(eventdate)) -7)Eventdate from     SP_HS_Marketing_ExtEvents WHERE __ApprovalStatus = 'Approved' and __EventType not in ('1','-1','-2')
group by ID, __DisplayName
Union ALL
Select  id,__DisplayName, 
LEFT(cast(min(EventDate) as varchar), len(min(eventdate)) -7) + ' - ' +  LEFT(cast(max(EventDate) as     varchar), len(max(eventdate)) -7) Eventdate from SP_HS_Marketing_ExtEvents WHERE  __ApprovalStatus =     'Approved' and __EventType = -2
group by ID, __DisplayName)
```

[image]
Thank you, 
Adam

Comment: Please do not post images. Post plain text and format it as "code" for tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you can use a CTE to find the min and max dates, then join back to the original table and concat + cast the date.

```
With cte as (
Select min(eventdate) as minDate, max(eventdate) as maxDate, Id 
from   SP_HS_Marketing_ExtEvents 
WHERE __ApprovalStatus = 'Approved' and __EventType not in ('1','-1','-2')
group by id
        )

        Select Distinct s.EventTitle,
        DATENAME(MONTH,cte.minDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(DAY,cte.minDate) + ' ' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR(cte.minDate) AS VARCHAR),2)
        + ' - ' +
        DATENAME(MONTH,cte.maxDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(DAY,cte.maxDate) + ' ' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(YEAR(cte.maxDate) AS VARCHAR),2) AS EventDate
        ,EventTime
        ,Location

        from  SP_HS_Marketing_ExtEvents as s
        join cte as cte
        on cte.ID = s.id
```

[Rextester](http://rextester.com/SJY33372)